# Auto Complete triggers RequiredFieldValidator in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a login form and a register form side by side.

In IE, on the login side if you pick a value for the username from the dropdown, the register side validation is triggered on the password field. But you can still login because all the controls/buttons are wired to their specific validation groups. And there is no value entered in the textbox...just the validation gets triggered?

[image: image description]

It doesn't do this in Firefox or Chrome, and while it doesn't prevent the user from doing anything, it's a little distracting.

The only thing I've been able to discover so far is that it's related to the  " TextMode="Password" " attribute on the right form. If I remove this everything works fine.

Is there anyway to stop having IE do this without writing some code to dynamically change the textmode once the register form starts being filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the javascript option that detects focus on the password box and sets the mode. If anyone ever comes up with anything better I would love to hear it!